# Matlab - Genetic algorithm for mixed integer optimization

Tags: algorithm, matlab, anonymous-function, genetic-algorithm

The problem that I am trying to solve is based on the following code:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/solving-a-mixed-integer-engineering-design-problem-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html

My function has a lot more variables but basically it is the same. I have a set of variables that needs to be optimized under given constraints. Some of the variables have to be discrete. However, they can only take the values 0 and 1, I don't have to specify them, as it is shown in the example. (I have tried both methods though)

First I create the upper and lower boundaries, which creates a variable of size `1x193`, respectively.

```
[lb,ub] = GWO_LUBGA(n_var,n_comp,C,n_comp);
```

Afterwards I call up the constraints. As I have discrete values, I cannot use equality constraints. Therefore I am using the workaround that was proposed here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/mixed-integer-optimization.html

```
ObjCon = @(x) funconGA(x,C,ub,n_comp);
```

Same for the objective function:

```
ObjFcn = @(x) CostFcnGA(x,C);
```

Afterwards I pass it over to the genetic algorithm:

```
[Pos,Best,~,GWO_cg_curve] = ga(ObjFcn,n_var,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,ObjCon,C.T*6+2:C.T*8+1,opts);
```

with `n_var = 193` and `C.T=24`

When I try to compile I receive the following error:

**Error using ga (line 366)
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.**

Line 366 contains the following code. Unfortunately gaminlp cannot be opened.

```
% Call appropriate single objective optimization solver
if ~isempty(intcon)   
[x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = gaminlp(FitnessFcn,nvars, ...
    Aineq,bineq,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,NonconFcn,intcon,options,output,Iterate);
```

Both anonymous functions work when random values are entered. What could be the reason for this error?